# How to disable access by article id in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, article

I am trying to disable a direct access by article id in Joomla 2.5. For example, http://domain.com/6 will display an article with id number 6 (http://domain.com/6 should redirect to error page). This can be reproduced with default 2.5 installation (using sample data) http://domain.com/index.php/6 which will display "Australian Parks". I prefer not to use ".htaccess" or apache rewrites if possible. "Search Engine Friendly URLs" is being used in the project.

Thanks

Comment: That's a bizarre URL for joomla. Typically, a Joomla 2.5 URL would be something like `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6` for Article ID of 6. If Google indexing is your issue, it might be better to change your robots.txt and also use Webmaster Tools to remove any current indexed pages you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a menu item for your article with access level "special". This will deny access to the article to all but admins. You can also do this from the article itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are not trying to prevent public access to the article, but rather accessing it via article ID in the URL. The problem is that one of our articles got indexed by google (http://domain.com/6) and I am not sure how because I believe I have no such link referenced (perhaps google indexed it because somebody manually searched for it and it returned 200).

Answer (score 0):

Try plugin JL NO DOUBLES - it do the trick (redirect to page with proper alias)